# Resize content on browser resize without flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want the content to shrink horizontally when the browser is resized.

It works perfectly if I assign `display: flex` to `jp-controls`. However I need to support IE9 so I can't use flex. How do I do the equivalent but with support for IE9?

To see what it does currently, open Dev tools => Mobile Device and choose the resolution 372 x 300 to see the content overflowing

https://jsfiddle.net/3ej343z4/1/

What I want (but without using `display: flex`, notice how no overflowing):

[image]

What it does currently:

[image]

Html:

```
<div class="jp-sleek jp-jplayer jp-audio jp-state-volume-low">
  <div class="jp-gui" style="opacity: 1;">
    <div class="jp-controls jp-icon-controls">
      <button class="jp-play"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></button>
      <div class="jp-playback-rate-bar">
        <div class="jp-playback-rate-bar-value" style="width: 14.2857%;"></div>
      </div>
      <button class="jp-repeat"><i class="fa fa-repeat"></i></button>
      <div class="jp-progress">
      </div>
      <button class="jp-full-screen"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i></button>
      <div class="jp-title-container"><img class="jp-poster" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bM7SZ5SBzyY/hqdefault.jpg">
        <div class="jp-title">Fade</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.jp-sleek {
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
}

.jp-sleek .jp-gui {
    height: 42px;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    position: relative;
}

.fa {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-controls {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 24px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-controls button {
    color: #000;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-controls > * {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-playback-rate-bar {
    background-color: #a1c1f4;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 60px;
    min-width: 30px;
}

.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-playback-rate-bar .jp-playback-rate-bar-value {
    background-color: #71a6fc;
    height: 100%;
    width: 14%;
}

.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-icon-controls button {
    min-width: 42px;
}

.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-icon-controls .jp-progress {
    background-color: #a1c1f4;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 180px;
    max-width: 500px;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-title-container {
    font-size: 12px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.jp-audio.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-title-container .jp-poster {
    max-height: 100%;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-title-container .jp-title {
    font-weight: bold;
    max-width: 135px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tables can behave like flexboxes:

```
.jp-controls {
  display: table;
  height: inherit; /*42px from the parent*/
}

.jp-controls > * {
  height: inherit;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

I've marked the css changes in the code:
jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3ej343z4/3/

Comment: This works well. I am just hoping not to use tables as they are really for tabular data only (or so I have read). I'v read tables have accessibility problems

Comment: CSS "`display:table`" does not change the semantics of any element. The [...] effects are just visual layout effects, which is the domain of CSS. -- see further [explanation here](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/297807/is-the-table-tag-and-displaytable-a-functional-or-a-layout-directive)

Answer (score 0):

Use `calc()` function to calculate `.jp-progress` width (100% - sum of width of the other controls).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/md3hgwfd/)

```css
.jp-controls {
  display: flex;
}
.jp-sleek {
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
}
.jp-sleek .jp-gui {
  height: 42px;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  position: relative;
}
.fa {
  font-size: 24px;
}
.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-controls {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 24px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-controls button {
  color: #000;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-controls > * {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-playback-rate-bar {
  background-color: #a1c1f4;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 60px;
  min-width: 30px;
}
.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-playback-rate-bar .jp-playback-rate-bar-value {
  background-color: #71a6fc;
  height: 100%;
  width: 14%;
}
.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-icon-controls button {
  min-width: 42px;
}
.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-icon-controls .jp-progress {
  background-color: #a1c1f4;
  width: calc(100% - 42px - 60px - 42px - 42px - 100px);
  min-width: 180px;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-title-container {
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 12px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.jp-audio.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-title-container .jp-poster {
  max-height: 100%;
}
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-title-container .jp-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  max-width: 135px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="jp-sleek jp-jplayer jp-audio jp-state-volume-low">
  <div class="jp-gui" style="opacity: 1;">
    <div class="jp-controls jp-icon-controls">
      <button class="jp-play"><i class="fa fa-play"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="jp-playback-rate-bar">
        <div class="jp-playback-rate-bar-value" style="width: 14.2857%;"></div>
      </div>
      <button class="jp-repeat"><i class="fa fa-repeat"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="jp-progress">
      </div>
      <button class="jp-full-screen"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="jp-title-container">
        <img class="jp-poster" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bM7SZ5SBzyY/hqdefault.jpg">
        <div class="jp-title">Fade</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't really want to hard code values like this because their can be x Number of other controls as I am supplying my CSS as part of an npm package so it should just work the same with 0 or 10 controls

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <div class="jp-sleek jp-jplayer jp-audio jp-state-volume-low">
  <div class="jp-gui" style="opacity: 1;">
    <div class="jp-controls jp-icon-controls">
    <div class="left">
      <button class="jp-play"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></button>
      <div class="jp-playback-rate-bar">
        <div class="jp-playback-rate-bar-value" style="width: 14.2857%;"></div>
      </div>
      <button class="jp-repeat"><i class="fa fa-repeat"></i></button>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
      <button class="jp-full-screen"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i></button>
      <div class="jp-title-container"><img class="jp-poster" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bM7SZ5SBzyY/hqdefault.jpg">
        <div class="jp-title">Fade</div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="jp-progress">
      <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


.right {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}
.jp-sleek {
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
}

.jp-sleek .jp-gui {
    height: 42px;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    position: relative;
}

.fa {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-controls {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 24px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-controls button {
    color: #000;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-controls .left > *, .jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-controls .right > * {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-playback-rate-bar {
    background-color: #a1c1f4;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 60px;
    min-width: 30px;
}

.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-playback-rate-bar .jp-playback-rate-bar-value {
    background-color: #71a6fc;
    height: 100%;
    width: 14%;
}

.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-icon-controls button {
    min-width: 42px;
}

.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-icon-controls .jp-progress {
    padding-left: 200px;
    padding-right: 170px;
    height: 100%;
}

.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-icon-controls .jp-progress div {
    background-color: #a1c1f4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-title-container {
    font-size: 12px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.jp-audio.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-title-container .jp-poster {
    max-height: 100%;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-title-container .jp-title {
    font-weight: bold;
    max-width: 135px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Live demo - https://jsfiddle.net/grinmax_/3ej343z4/5/